# Override (shorten) breadcrumbs on Views page

Tags: 7, views, breadcrumbs, theming

I'm using Views 3 and I DON'T want the contextual filter to tack itself onto the end of the breadcrumb. In fact, for the whole view, I want only the static breadcrumb Home » My View Name. That's it. Nothing changed or added no matter what contextual filter I click, as long as I'm inside the view.

I tried doing an `array_slice($breadcrumb)` inside my view's tpl.php file but it seems to have no effect. However, in the same template, `$breadcrumb[] = 'salamanders'` gives me the word 'salamanders' as the second to last item in my breadcrumb. It does this regardless of whether I have my contextual filter set to override breadcrumb or not, and also irrespective of what text I've actually entered to override it with, when override enabled.

I've tried overriding the breadcrumb in hook_page_alter() inside a custom module as well. Again, I can add to but not subtract from the breadcrumb.

How do I remove elements from my breadcrumb when Views insists on tacking things on to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're open for contributed modules, I'd suggest that you try [Path breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs). This module will allow you to set up breadcrumb definitions, depending on the path of the page. There you define all items to appear as breadcrumbs, and thus specify whether you want the last item or not, linked or not.

Comment: It's not just the last item that I want to get rid of, it's all except the first two.

Comment: With that module, YOU are the sheriff ;-)

Comment: Sheriff or not, it doesn't seem to prevent Views from adding a breadcrumb element after the breadcrumb has been set.

Comment: Have you removed any custom code that you used previously for managing breadcrumbs and cleared the cache? This might interfere. Are you perhaps using contextual filter in your View - there's a Override breadcrumb checkbox (not sure about the label though) which might be coming into play.

Comment: I've tried checking and unchecking the override breadcrumb option in the contextual filter, to no avail.

Comment: I figured it out - it was taking breadcrumbs from the page title. So I wasn't overriding breadcrumbs, but I was overriding page titles. Quit overriding page titles, and everything went nice.

Comment: Glad to hear it!